# Create MMF to play sounds from MemoryStream with Mediaplayer class

Tags: .net, powershell

Many sounds are being generated in real time so I can't play them simultaneously with `System.Media.SoundPlayer` from new thread/runspace.
The only way to overcome this limitation is to run my 100 script blocks as new processes:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoExit -Command $Synth001"
...
Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoExit -Command $Synth100"
```

It's an awful workaround to start 100 powershell processes becuse I want to use `SoundPlayer`.
Due to the long delay, playing generated `wav` files from the storage with `Mediaplayer` is not an option!

Option 1: How to create memory mapped file and play it with `System.Windows.Media.Mediaplayer`?

Option 2: How to create completely isolated, non-thread-safe runspace from same PS instance so new `SoundPlayer` classes will not interact on each other?

C# examples could be helpful.

Comment: What is the end goal here? ie. what are you trying to _accomplish_ by having PowerShell play multiple wav files simultanesouly?

Comment: Synthesizer, not an object of discussion, with dynamic wave forms. That's why I stick to reading data from memory, not from HDD.